# How to set a Background in COCOS2D android?

Tags: android, background, cocos2d-android

I want to set an image , download from a URL, to the COCOS2D android, as a background.
My Class is CCGLSurfaceView.  Here is my Code.
how can i set Image to it from Internet as a background.

```
package org.cocos2d.opengl;


public class CCGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {
private static final int VIEWID = 0x1235;
// private static final String LOG_TAG = CCGLSurfaceView.class.getSimpleName();
private CCTouchDispatcher mDispatcher;

public CGSize frame;

public CCGLSurfaceView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    CCDirector.theApp = (Activity) context;

    mDispatcher = CCTouchDispatcher.sharedDispatcher();

    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    this.setId(VIEWID);

    // add this to resolve Samsung's Galaxy opengl problem
    //  here for reference.
    // http://www.anddev.org/samsung_galaxy_odd_ogl_es_hardware_acceleration_resolved-t8511.html
    /* need a real machine to test
    this.setEGLConfigChooser(
            new GLSurfaceView.EGLConfigChooser() {
                public EGLConfig chooseConfig(EGL10 egl,EGLDisplay display) {
                    int[] attributes=new int[]{
                            //EGL10.EGL_RED_SIZE,
                            //5,
                            //EGL10.EGL_BLUE_SIZE,
                            //5,
                            //EGL10.EGL_GREEN_SIZE,
                            //6,
                            EGL10.EGL_DEPTH_SIZE,
                            16,
                            EGL10.EGL_NONE
                    };
                    EGLConfig[] configs=new EGLConfig[1];
                    int[] result=new int[1];
                    egl.eglChooseConfig(display,attributes,configs,1,result);
                    return configs[0];
                }
            }
    );*/
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    frame = CGSize.make(right - left, bottom - top);
}        

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    mDispatcher.queueMotionEvent(event);

//      switch (event.getAction()) {
//      case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
//          mDispatcher.touchesCancelled(event);
//          break;
//      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
//          mDispatcher.touchesBegan(event);
//          break;
 //     case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
//          mDispatcher.touchesMoved(event);
  //            break;
//      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
//          mDispatcher.touchesEnded(event);
//          break;
//      }

    synchronized (CCDirector.sharedDirector()) {
        try {
            CCDirector.sharedDirector().wait(20L);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Do nothing
        }
    }

    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For setting a background image you need to define `CCSprite` in the constructor, set the tag to `1` and anchor point values to `(0,0)`.

Here is the code:

```
CCSprite background = CCSprite.sprite("Background.jpeg");
background.setTag(1);
background.setAnchorPoint(0, 0);
addChild(background);
```